# PentahoExecute SQL statement

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, data-migration, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I work with Pentaho as an ETL to migrate from the MSSQL database to the PostgreSQL database.

> ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-371, build 8.3.0.0-371 from 2019-06-11 11.09.08
>   by buildguy) : An error occurred executing this job entry :
>
> - Create table ["tablename"] - Couldn't execute SQL: CREATE TABLE "tablename"

```
   CREATE TABLE sysdiagrams
    (
    ,`name` VARCHAR(128)
    , principal_id int
    , diagram_id int
    , version int
    )
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to run your `CREATE TABLE` statement with an "SQL" job entry, the log shows the following :

```
2019/12/20 09:54:36 - SQL - ERROR (version 8.3.0.3-520, build 8.3.0.3-520 from 2019-09-20 07.35.24 by buildguy) : An error occurred executing this job entry : 
2019/12/20 09:54:36 - SQL - Couldn't execute SQL: CREATE TABLE sysdiagrams
        (
        ,`name` VARCHAR(128)
        , principal_id int
        , diagram_id int
        , version int
        )
2019/12/20 09:54:36 - SQL - 
2019/12/20 09:54:36 - SQL - ERREUR: erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « , »
  Position : 44
```

Removing the first comma in the column list, and removing the backticks ('`') around the `name` identifier solved the issue :

```
CREATE TABLE sysdiagrams
        (
        name VARCHAR(128)
        , principal_id int
        , diagram_id int
        , version int
        )
```

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer. I still have same error. 2019/12/20 00:27:51 - Create table [sysdiagrams] - ERROR (version 8.3.0.0-371, build 8.3.0.0-371 from 2019-06-11 11.09.08 by buildguy) : An error occurred executing this job entry : 
- Create table [sysdiagrams] - Couldn't execute SQL: CREATE TABLE sysdiagrams

 - `name` VARCHAR(128)
 - , principal_id int
 - Create table [sysdiagrams] - , diagram_id int
 , version int
 
 ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"
 Position: 28

Comment: My bad, I was testing it with a MySQL connection, which doesn't respond to the same syntax rules as PostgreSQL. By running it again on a PostgreSQL connection, I also get an additional error. I was able to solve it by removing the backticks ('`') around the 'name' identifier. Backticks are considered non-standard SQL (as stated [here](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Things_to_find_out_about_when_moving_from_MySQL_to_PostgreSQL))

Comment: Thank you but.This method did not work for me. When I did this E.g. “create table schemaname.tablename(“, my problem was solved.I got the same error on a different table but this time it didn't work. Any idea? It's around 1200 line so I can't add here.